# Efficiently retrieving people and the task most recently assigned to them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following simple setup:

```
create_table "people", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
end

create_table "tasks", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "description"
  t.integer  "person_id"
  t.date     "started_on"
  t.date     "ended_on"
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

Assuming that tasks assigned to a person never overlap in time,

- How would you efficiently retrieve each person's most recent job?
- Also, how would you select all the people who, as of Date.today, are without a job?

So far I have been able to figure out solutions with inefficient queries and lots of ruby code. I wonder instead if ActiveRecord offers idiomatic ways to construct such searches.

I thought, for example, to search the most recent jobs this way:

```
Task.group(:person_id).maximum(:ended_on)
```

but what I get is an ActiveSupport::OrderedHash, whereas I do need the Task models and associated people.

Thanks!
Giuseppe

Answer (score 0):

In Person model

```
def last_job
     self.jobs.order("started_on DESC").limit(1)
end
```

You can write a `scope` to filter jobs for "open" jobs that havent been finished like this:

```
scope :finished_jobs, where("ended_on IS NOT NULL")
scope :unfinished_jobs, where("ended_on IS NULL")
```

So you can also do

```
def is_unemployeed?
     self.jobs.unfinished_jobs.empty?
end
```

Comment: Right, so, this solution implies iterating over the list of people and inspecting the associated tasks. To do this, I would probably include all tasks in the original Person search, and then find the latest task via ruby (e.g. self.tasks.max_by { |t| t.ended_on }). But this does not respond to the second question, i.e. retrieving with a search only the people who are currently not engaged in a task. I am still wondering if this can be done with a clever ActiveRecord search. Thanks!